# React js summernote editor value to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the summernote editor code:

`<textarea id="textfield" name="content"  placeholder="Content" className="form-control editor1" onChange={this.handlechange} ></textarea>`

when using the summernote editor, how to send value to state?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a good start. Please also include some description of what you've tried so far, (best if it includes code or pseudo code). If you put a little more effort into your question you will be more likely to get more, and higher value answers. Also you will help anyone else with a similar question find the good answers you received.

Answer (score 1):

I register the summernote on componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
  $('#textfield').summernote()
}
```

As [summernote documentation](http://summernote.org/deep-dive/#onchange), You can get callback on onChange event of summernote. Then you can set the state on the call back.

```
  componentDidMount() {
   var that = this; // use var that to point this class
   $('#textfield').summernote({
       callbacks : {
       onChange: function(contents) {
           that.setState({text: contents})
       }
     }
   })
  }
```

Here is my updated fidlle, you can learn from it
https://jsfiddle.net/firhatsungkar/999apkLu/1/

Comment: Hi there,I am using summernote editor and it hides the textarea and render its field so i cannot send the value to state. hope you get what i am saying

Comment: I'm sorry for my last answer. I got it now. Then I try to re-answer. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Add a refs property:

```
<textarea id="textfield" name="content"  
     placeholder="Content" className="form-control editor1" 
     onChange={this.handlechange} 
     refs={element => this.initializeEditor(element)} />
```

Initialize the editor:

```
initializeEditor(element) {
     this.editor = $(element).summernote({ .... });
}
```

Then do everything on the this.editor like normal.

Comment: Hi there,I am using summernote editor and it hides the textarea and render its field so i cannot send the value to state. hope you get what i am saying.